# Best way to compute sign() of Eigen::Matrix

Tags: c++, math, matrix, eigen

Since the Eigen C++ library does not contain a built-in way for computing the `sign(x)` of a matrix I am looking for the best method of doing this. For a definition of `sign()` see the [Matlab documentation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sign.html), although I don't really need the case for 0 elements. The method I came up with is the following.

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXf a = Eigen::MatrixXf(2,2);
a << -0.5, 1.0,
      0.3, -1.4;

// Temporary objects containing 1's and -1's
const Eigen::MatrixXi pos = Eigen::MatrixXi::Ones(a.rows(), a.cols());
const Eigen::MatrixXi neg = Eigen::MatrixXi::Ones(a.rows(), a.cols()) * -1;

// Actually filling of the matrix sign(a)
Eigen::MatrixXi a_sign = (a.array() >= 0).select(pos, neg);

std::cout << a << std::endl << std::endl;
std::cout << a_sign << std::end;
```

This works so the output is given by

```
-0.5    1
 0.3 -1.4

-1  1
 1 -1
```

However I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this? Creating the two temporary matrices seems cumbersome and can get rather slow when dealing with very large matrices.

Comment: what's wrong with [`Eigen::MatrixXi a_sign = a.cwiseSign();`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#ae0311bc942689d047292cc62e75e02a9)?

Comment: There is no such function available (Eigen 3.2.6)

Comment: well looks like it was added on Nov 25 2015, anyways, then how about. `Eigen::MatrixXi a_sign = a.unaryExpr([](float in){return in<0?-1:1;});` ? (since you said you didn't need the 0 case, but you can easily add that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `unaryExpr`?

```
double sign_func(double x)
{
    if (x > 0)
        return +1.0;
    else if (x == 0)
        return 0.0
    else
        return -1.0;
}

int main()
{
     Eigen::MatrixXf a = Eigen::MatrixXf(2,2);
     a << -0.5, 1.0,
           0.3, -1.4;
     std::cout << a.unaryExpr(std::ptr_fun(sign_func)) << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: This was spot on. I defined a lambda function right above where I called `unaryExpr` and passed it in without `std::ptr_fun`.

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
 X = X.array().sign();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now (Jan 2024).